# Detecting when thread has been closed

Tags: c#

In my `C#` application, I have a separate window containing a progress bar that runs in a separate thread. Every 30 seconds it sends a request for data from a server and fills the progress bar accordingly.

The problem is, when I close the main program, the second window with the progress bar stays open.

How can I program the second thread to detect when the first thread has been closed, and close itself accordingly?

Comment: Is second thread a background thread?

Comment: How about responding to the closing event and manualy terminate the second thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Window_Closed Event from your first Window:

```
private void Window1_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Window2.Close(); // Close your second window
}
```

And then in second Window:

```
private void Window2_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // abort all Threads
    thread.Abort();
}
```

Comment: Closing a window will not necessarily close down any background threads.

Comment: @Andy thanks. I used the FormClosed event on the first form like you suggested, and then used `thread.Abort()` - which closed the second window as well as aborting the second thread.

Answer (score 0):

Make the working thread into a Background thread. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0.aspx

Closing a child thread from its parent thread is not recommended since this
will most likely prevents some resources from being correctly released.